# jquery ajax with async false hangs firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, asynchronous

I have a code that calls $.ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({

                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/sandbox/graphloader/mock3",
                        async: false,
                        data: {calInput1:dates[0], calInput2:dates[1]},
                        success: function(data){
                            data=eval(data);
                            for(var x in data[0]){
                                //alert(data[0][x]);
                                //fill columns here;
                            }

                            fillPercents(column);
                        }});
```

now, this works in all browsers, other than Firefox. firebug shows it is getting reply back from post, but for some unknown error, it is not displaying the data.
What might be the problem ?

Comment: The problem is firefox never finishes loading. I am using a jquery ui for showing columns that are populated with data returned from ajax, the data never gets populated.

Comment: What happens if you put a `console.log` or `alert` call at the beginning of the callback? Do you see any errors in Firebug?

Comment: What type of data is returned by the ajax call(ie json, xml, html etc)... can you give a sample... Whether your eval function is returning successfully?

Comment: alert responds. it just doesn't fill up the data. looks like it hangs in..  and no errors in firebug.

Comment: before putting async:false, the data was being represented properly. the data passed is json, from php, a multidimension array.

Comment: then you can set a property `dataType:'json'` in the ajax call then no need to use `eval()` to process the data. jQuery will process the data and pass it as the `data` argument. Can you put a break point in the firebug and try to see what is going wrong

Comment: dude, data is fine imho, the flow is fine, I am just seeing it inconsistent if I remove async:false. if I put it back, it doesn't work in firefox, but works in other browsers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behavior is by design.

*Never* use `async: false`.
Since Javascript runs on the UI thread, an `async: false` request will freeze the browser until the server replies.

Comment: "until server replies" is ok. let it freeze. but once the server replies, it should be normal right ??

Comment: **No, DON'T let it freeze**.  This is the surest (OK, almost surest) way to drive users away from your site.

Comment: I see... ok, then I have a new problem. My ajax calls are supposed to fill 4 columns with data from server after a user changes date on the column. then there are calculations on this new data. I've also put the calculations part in the "success" function of jquery's ajax call. but the calculations are happening on the old data "sometimes". Can I avoid this ??

Comment: You're probably running them before the server replies.  Can you show your code?

Comment: original question updated to show the ajax call.. if you want more, let me know..

Comment: Are those calculations in the success callback of the ajax call or have you placed them after the ajax call(ie in the next line after $.ajax())

Comment: @arun : By "calculations" you mean the function fillPercents(i) ?   it is a function call dude, it is called "in" the $.ajax(), but the function is outside the ajax's success callback. Should it be the problem ??

Comment: @Shrinath ~ Listen to @SLaks one more time. **DON'T let it freeze** ... there's just no reason to use synchronous code from javascript. Instead, block the UI in some other fashion to notify the user that you're still working. But **DON'T let it freeze**

Comment: ok, <b>lets remove async:false</b>, but the fillPercents() seems to be taking old data, and not the new data that came from ajax. This doesn't happen always, but sometimes. Shows inconsistent behaviour

Comment: shall we use setTimeout("fillPercents("+column+")",2000); to delay the calculation of percentages ??

Comment: @Shrinath: At the very least, you should pass a function to setTimeout, not a string.  However, you should be able to debug this problem.

Comment: @SLaks: but dude, setTimeout() takes a function name as a string :) "fillPercents(columnNumber)" is my function to calculate percentages :)

Comment: And dude, setting delay for fillpercents did solve the problem. I guess it was taking the old data in columns to calculate the percents. Now I set a delay of 100ms, and it is working fine..  Now its working WITHOUT "async:false" and with setTimeout("fillpercents(columnNumber)",100);

Comment: @Shrinath: No.  `setTimeout` takes a function.  You should not pass a string.  Instead, write `setTimeout(function() { fillpercents(columnNumber); }, 100); `

Comment: @SLaks : what about this ? : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp And I am using the same syntax which is working. What is the advantage of using the function instead of string ??

Comment: @Shrinath: Passing a function is much faster.  Do not look to W3Scoohls for best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Your `columns` global might be getting overwritten by a previous AJAX request.

Try making it a local variable in the callback, and try adding `console.log` calls to ensure that the callback order is what you expect.

---

You may need to keep a global request counter to ensure that you don't process a response after sending a new request.

For example:

```
var lastRequest = 0;   //You may want to put this in a namespace or closure

...

var thisRequest = ++lastRequest;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/sandbox/graphloader/mock3",
    async: false,
    data: {calInput1:dates[0], calInput2:dates[1]},
    success: function(data){
        if (thisRequest !== lastRequest) return;
        ...
    }});
```

Do not do this inside a loop body or you'll share the `thisRequest` variable.
Instead, call a function from the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

It's freezing because it's not getting a 'success' response and you haven't handled the error. Set an `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}` in you settings to handle the error response. `async: false` works fine.