# Javascript variable does not update via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I believe I haven't fully grasped variable scope in jQuery and need some help to understand why the variable "final_shasign" comes out fine inside the AJAX but is undefined outside the AJAX despite it being declared outside of the AJAX.

```
var final_shasign; // initial declaration outside of ajax block below

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sha.php",
    data: "amount="+amount+"&cn="+cn+"&currency="+currency+"&language="+language+"&orderid="+orderid+"&pspid="+pspid,
    success: function(response_data, final_shasign){
        var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(response_data);
        final_shasign = parsed_data.shasign;
        console.log ("inside nested ajax: " + final_shasign); //comes out fine
    }
});

console.log ("outside of nested ajax: " + final_shasign); //comes out as undefined!
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 3):

This is because your `console.log()` outside of the AJAX statement is being executed **before** the AJAX response has returned and updated the variable value.

[**AJAX is asynchronous**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932690/why-is-ajax-called-asynchronous) so your code after the AJAX statement will run before the response has had chance to be returned from "sha.php".

If you wish to prevent the request acting asynchronously, you can set `async:false` on the `$.ajax()` method.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sha.php",
    data: "amount="+amount+"&cn="+cn+"&currency="+currency+"&language="+language+"&orderid="+orderid+"&pspid="+pspid,
    async: false,
    success: function(response_data, final_shasign){
        var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(response_data);
        final_shasign = parsed_data.shasign;
        console.log ("inside nested ajax: " + final_shasign); //comes out fine
    }
});
```

[**But this isn't recommended!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902174/tactics-to-avoid-using-asyncfalse-with-jquery) Instead any javascript which is reliant on the AJAX response should be called in the `success` callback function.

```
var final_shasign;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sha.php",
    data: "amount="+amount+"&cn="+cn+"&currency="+currency+"&language="+language+"&orderid="+orderid+"&pspid="+pspid,
    async: false,
    success: function(response_data, final_shasign){
        var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(response_data);
        final_shasign = parsed_data.shasign;
        console.log ("inside nested ajax: " + final_shasign); //comes out fine
        Func();
    }
});

function Func(){
   console.log ("outside of nested ajax: " + final_shasign);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is asynchronous, so at time you try to read value of variable outside the ajax callback functions, it's still `undefined`.

So code your logic using variable value inside the callback function, here `success` callback.

You could use a defered object too.

Please read that: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
success: function(response_data, final_shasign){
    var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(response_data);
    final_shasign = parsed_data.shasign;

    passFinalvalue(final_shasign) 
    console.log ("inside nested ajax: " + final_shasign); //comes out fine
}

function passFinalvalue(getval)
{
 //do your stuff
}
```